# Preventing user from calling Parent functions

Tags: java, android, oop

**UPDATE(24/10/19)** : I modified the language of the question a little bit. Downvoters, if its still unclear, please let me know publicly via comments, so I could refine it more (I  just see a closing vote saying unclear, neither the mod name nor the reason). Please know that English is not my first language and I really want help on this.

---

So i guess this is more related to java fundamentals and OOP, but i have seen some patterns followed by usual Android classes. Google is often deprecating old functions in favour of better functions, and I am thinking of doing something similar with my custom View.

I want to build a video player in android that should be easy to create and should be returning a callback on several events.  For that i want the user to use my functions instead of Built in video view's function. So i am applying several approaches to prevent user from using those built-in functions:

- I am using the `@Deprecated` notation to show the function name with a strike ,  eg <strike>`getVolume()`</strike>
- I have overriden those functions that i don't want user to use and replaced their implementation with errors like :

```
@Override @deprecated
public void getWidth(){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("useMyVideoPlayer#getVideoWidth()");
}
```

- I am implementing those functions by myself in `init()` or their respective alternatives. Here is the code( check the comment on the code line : `super.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);`)

```java
public class MyVideoPlayer extends VideoView {
    public static final String TAG = "MyVP>>";

    private MyPlayerCurrentPlaybackState currentPlaybackState;
    private MediaController mediaController;

    @Nullable
    private MyVideoPlayerListener playerListener;

    public MyVideoPlayer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }
    public MyVideoPlayer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    public MyVideoPlayer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }
    public MyVideoPlayer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        currentPlaybackState = MyPlayerCurrentPlaybackState.STOPPED;
        mediaController = new MediaController(this.getContext());
        mediaController.setAnchorView(this);

        MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.e(TAG, "internalListener:onCompletion: called");
                mp.reset();
                mp.setDisplay(MyVideoPlayer.this.getHolder());
                currentPlaybackState = MyPlayerCurrentPlaybackState.STOPPED;
                if (playerListener != null) {
                    playerListener.onCompleted(mp);
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onCompletionListener:onCompletion: playerListener is null");
                }

            }
        };
        super.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);

        MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener errorListener = new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                currentPlaybackState = MyPlayerCurrentPlaybackState.STOPPED;
                if (playerListener != null) {
                    playerListener.onError(what, extra);
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "errorListener:onError: playerListener is null");

                }
                return true;// indicates we handled error

            }
        };
        super.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);// <---setting error listener *inside* the view only and making setOnErrorListener(...) deprecated so that user won't use it

        MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener preparedListener = new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                //play(); // or should we call mp.start?
                if (playerListener != null) {
                    playerListener.onPlayerPrepared(MyVideoPlayer.this);
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "preparedListener:onPrepared: player listener is null");
                }
            }
        };
        super.setOnPreparedListener(preparedListener);




    }

    @Nullable
    public MyVideoPlayerListener getMyPlayerListener() {
        return playerListener;
    }

    public void setMyPlayerListener(@NonNull MyVideoPlayerListener playerListener) {
        this.playerListener = playerListener;
    }

    //---------following methods throw exception, do not use-----vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

    @Override @Deprecated
    public void setOnCompletionListener(@Nullable MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener implementorsListener) {
        //update: user is now not adding the on completion listener at all. he/she will only use our methods now.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Use MyVideoPlayer#setMyPlayerListener(...) ");
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public void setOnErrorListener(MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener implementorsListener) {
        //update: user is now not adding the on completion listener at all. he/she will only use our methods now.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Use MyVideoPlayer#setMyPlayerListener(...) ");
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public int getDuration() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Use MyVideoPlayer#gettotalDuration(...) ");
    }

    @Deprecated
    public void start() {
        // did because it doesn't look cool
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Use MyVideoPlayer#play() ");
    }

    @Override @Deprecated
    public void stopPlayback() {
        // did because it doesn't look cool
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Use MyVideoPlayer#stop() ");
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @Override @Deprecated
    public void setOnPreparedListener(MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener implementorsListener) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("use MyVideoPlayer#onPlayerPrepared()");
    }



    public void play() {
        super.start();
        if (playerListener != null) {
            playerListener.onPlay();
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "play: player listener is null");
        }
        currentPlaybackState = MyPlayerCurrentPlaybackState.PLAYING;
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // didn't throwed any exception because its already cool

        super.pause();

        currentPlaybackState = MyPlayerCurrentPlaybackState.PAUSED;

        if (playerListener != null) {
            playerListener.onPause();
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "play: player listener is null");
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // didn't throwed any exception because its already cool

        super.start();
        if (playerListener != null) {
            playerListener.onResume();
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "play: player listener is null");
        }
        currentPlaybackState = MyPlayerCurrentPlaybackState.PLAYING;

    }

    public void stop() {
        if (currentPlaybackState != MyPlayerCurrentPlaybackState.STOPPED) {
            super.stopPlayback();
            if (playerListener != null) {
                playerListener.onStop();
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "play: player listener is null");
            }
            currentPlaybackState = MyPlayerCurrentPlaybackState.STOPPED;
        }
    }


    public int gettotalDuration() {
        return currentPlaybackState ==
                MyPlayerCurrentPlaybackState.STOPPED ? 0 : super.getDuration();
    }

    //returns current video volume in range 0-100
    public int getVolume() {
        // Get the system's audio service and get media volume from it.
        AudioManager audioManager =
                (AudioManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audioManager != null) {
            double volume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            double max = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            if (max <= 0) {
                return 0;
            }
            // Return a range from 0-100.
            return (int) ((volume / max) * 100.0f);
        }
        return 0;
    }


    public enum MyPlayerCurrentPlaybackState {
        STOPPED, PAUSED, PLAYING
    }


    public interface MyVideoPlayerListener {
        void onPlay();

        void onPause();

        void onResume();

        void onCompleted(MediaPlayer mp);

        void onError( int what, int extra);

        void onPlayerPrepared(MyVideoPlayer myVideoPlayer);

        void onStop();
    }



    /* must implement features
    public interface VideoPlayer {

    void play();
    void pause();
    void resume();
    int getCurrentPosition();
    void seekTo(int videoPosition);
    int getDuration();
    int getVolume();
    void stopPlayback();
    void disablePlaybackControls();
    void enablePlaybackControls();
    void setVideoPath(String videoUrl);
    void addPlayerCallback(PlayerCallback callback);
    void removePlayerCallback(PlayerCallback callback);

}
    *
    * */


}
```

I hope the above example shows my intentions: i want user to **NOT USE** built in methods like `start()` , `setOnErrorListener(...)`, etc , but the library would either handle those functions itself (and give a callback to user) or has defined some other functions that i want the user to use, instead of built in functions( for eg i want user to call custom views' `play()` function instead of already present `start()` function coming from the parent via [inheritance.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)))

But when I call the code via these lines:

```java
        MyVideoPlayer mvp = findViewById(R.id.mvp_main);
        mvp.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(MyTags.CONTENT_URL));
        mvp.setMyPlayerListener(new MyVideoPlayer.MyVideoPlayerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlay() {
                Log.e(TAG, "onPlay: Video is now playing" );
            }

            @Override
            public void onPause() {
                Log.e(TAG, "onPause: Video Paused" );
            }

            @Override
            public void onResume() {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResume: video resumed" );

            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(MediaPlayer mp) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onCompleted: video playback completed" );

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int what, int extra) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onError: error happenned: what:"+what+",extra:"+extra );
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerPrepared(MyVideoPlayer myVideoPlayer) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onPlayerPrepared: video is prepared,plau video" );
                myVideoPlayer.play();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStop() {
                Log.e(TAG, "onStop: media playback stopped" );

            }
        });
```

i.e when the user uses my library in their app, It would give  an exception whens calling those library defined functions like `mvp.play()` saying `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Use MyVideoPlayer#play()` , indicating my overridden `start()` function is being called instead of `super.start()` . Why? Also, am I using the `@Deprecated` annotation correctly (that is just for the sake of showing a strikethrough warning) or does this annotation make some unwanted changes as well?

Comment: "i want user to NOT USE built in methods like start() , setOnErrorListener(...), etc" -- then, as the answer outlines, you should not be extending a class that has those methods. "does this annotation make some unwanted changes as well?" -- no, that is purely for the use by IDEs and similar build tools. It has no runtime impact.

Comment: "I want to build a video player in android that should be easy to create and should be returning a callback on several events." -- I would not have that API *be* a `View`. If I absolutely needed something that went directly in a layout resource, I would use a `Fragment`. Otherwise, I would encapsulate the rest of the logic in a custom class that can tie into a developer-supplied `SurfaceView` or `TextureView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can apply proxy/decoration pattern:

write you own Videoplayer to implement and extend those classes that the original Vidoeview implements.
here is the a pseudo code which could give you a idea:

```
     //extends and implements the same interface and parent as the VideoView did, o that they will have the same methods to work properly.
      public  class MyVideoViewer extends SurfaceView implements 
          MediaController.MediaPlayerControl{
      //private modifier to prevent others from directly calling the system's player
      private VideoView view;

      //you can just delete start method, so users using your player cannot even see this method.
       /**void  start(){

      }*/

     public void init(){
       // do your things. can necessary method from videoplayer
       view.setOnCompletionListener(listener) etc.

    }
     public void play()
     {
        view.start();
    }
    //indirectly call all necessary methods to make sure the system's player work properly. 
   @override
    public void draw(arg1,arg2){
        view.draw(arg1,arg2);
     }
}
```

by doing, your player only exposes the methods you want it to expose, hide all the unnecessary methods behind your users. still it can work properly, because underneath, there is a proper system Videoview working for your player.

Comment: will this really work? I have a couple of questions regarding this: 1) since view is never initialised , won't it give a null pointer when calling its functions? 2) if video view is itself a class extending Suface View, Why are we again extending our video player with an surface view? If that's just for registering our class as a view, can't we simply use `class MyVideoPlayer extends View{...}` ?

Comment: 1: this is a pseudo code. you probably need to new a VideoView in your constructor. 2) your player has to extends and implements the same interface and class as the Videoviewer did. because  android system will be one who eventually call your view and draw it on the screen. if your didn't implement classes such as SurfaceView, which might have some special methods just for video playing, the system may end up complaining "cannot find the method xxxx"

Comment: 1. so just a statement `VideoView vv = new VideoView(this);` in the `init()` followed by all of my functions and other stuff?

Comment: you can check out this page https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/proxy-design-pattern/  .. and write a few classes to have a feeling about this pattern.

Comment: I think am able to somewhat understand this. let me try and come back to this question. I just hope it gets enough upvotes so it doesn't closes

Comment: the basic idea is whenever others call your player's method, you call the systems' player, and you also don't let your users know what you are having. it's like you are the boss, whoever asks you for a job done, you pass it to your worker. but your client will never know who has done it and they have no idea what extra functions your workers have got

Comment: Okay I found 2 problems with this approach: 1) The `VideoView` class also implements some `SubtitleController.Anchor`.class which shows Red in my AS, and i am guess that its not accessible 2) on implementing the other interface `MediaController.MediaPlayerControl`, functions like `onStart()` and `getDurations()` also get implemented . Thus i think, the problem is in 2 parts : preventing user from calling some functions by implementing it on our own and preventing user from calling some functions by hiding/not allowing user to call them. Your answer handles case 1  but doesn't handles case 2

Comment: because MediaController.MediaPlayerControl is specialized for Videoview and all of the methods in it are called by human, not android system, you just don't need to implement it.